# Setting property values on an instance from an IEnumerable<T> of named values

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I have 2 functions that are returning an `IEnumerable<Stat>`.

This function returns all the individual properties belonging to the `CharacterStats` class:

```
private IEnumerable<Stat> GetAllStats()
{
    yield return Level;
    yield return Health;
    yield return Damage;
    yield return Defense;
    //several others
    yield return LifePerSecond;
}
```

This function gets the stored (base) values from my newly added `sqlite` db:

```
private IEnumerable<Stat> GetBaseStatsFromDB()
{
    //connection code ...

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        yield return new Stat
        {
            Name = (Enums.StatName)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.StatName), rdr.GetString(1)),
            MinValue = rdr.GetInt32(2),
            MaxValue = rdr.GetInt32(3),
            CurrentValue = rdr.GetInt32(4)
        };
    }

    //close connection
}
```

What I would like to do is return a new instance of `CharacterStats` where each `Stat` is initialized from the DB and assigned to the instance, something like:

```
GetAllStats.ToList().ForEach( //apply matching stat from GetBaseStatsFromDB());
```

I am able to successfully get the values from the DB and create a new `Stat` object out of each. However, I've been unable to apply these values to the `CharacterStats` class.

There are currently ~ 16 stats and these may be added/removed as I continue building this project, so ideally I'd like to find a method that will continue to work as this list changes.

*How can I apply the result of `GetBaseStatsFromDB()` to all properties on `CharacterStats` by using the `GetAllStats()` method?*

**EDIT for clarification:**

`CharacterStats` is a class that holds the different `Stat`s that are generated. Example:

```
public class CharacterStats
{
    public Stat Level;
    public Stat Name;
    ...
    public Stat LifePerSecond;
}
```

`GetAllStats()` is a function used to enumerate each of these properties one at a time (like a list)

`GetBaseStatsFromDB()` is my attempt at initializing these values from the DB. What I would like to do is take **each individual property** on `CharacterStats` and apply the **matching** stat from `GetBaseStatsFromDB()`.

So ... `GetBaseStatsFromDB()` would return (in addition to others):

```
Stat
{
    Name = "Level",
    MinValue = 1,
    MaxValue = 50,
    CurrentValue = 1
}
```

I would like to take *this* result and apply it to the `Stat:Level` property on the `CharacterStats` class, then repeat for all additional stats.

Comment: The verb `apply` doesn't apply to enumerables, nor is `ForEach` necessary for any operation on IEnumerable. The question doesn't make much sense. What is `CharacterStats` and how is it related to `Stats` ? What are you trying to do? Create the combinations of both lists, like an outer Join? Or each database row as the value of a separate `CharacterStats` property of the same object? If so, what does `GetAllStats` have to do with the question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated the question in an attempt to clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is the obvious answer here (not the only one).

First, ensure that the values of `Enums.StatName` have names identical to the property names on `CharacterStats` (which I'm guessing you did anyway, because obvious).

```
//  Instance method of CharacterStats
public void SetStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
    var cstype = this.GetType();
    foreach (var stat in stats) {
        var prop = cstype.GetProperty(stat.Name.ToString());
        prop.SetValue(this, stat);
    }
}

//  Toss in a constructor too. 
public CharacterStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
    SetStats(stats);
}

//  And a factory method
public static FromStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
    return new CharacterStats(stats);
}
```

Use like so:

```
var stats = new CharacterStats(GetBaseStatsFromDB());
var stats2 = CharacterStats.FromStats(GetBaseStatsFromDB());

//  later on, maybe you want to copy stats from one to another... 
stats.SetStats(stats2.GetStats());
```

But if we may share `Stat` instances (and nothing in this code prevents that), it would be safer to clone the `Stat` instances when we copy them:

```
public Stat() { ... }
public Stat(Stat copyMe)
{
    this.Name = copyMe.Name;
    this.MinValue = copyMe.MinValue;
    this.MaxValue = copyMe.MaxValue;
    this.CurrentValue = copyMe.CurrentValue;
}
```

...and then...

```
//  This version is much safer. 
public void SetStats(IEnumerable<Stat> stats)
{
    var cstype = this.GetType();
    foreach (var stat in stats) {
        var prop = cstype.GetProperty(stat.Name.ToString());
        prop.SetValue(this, new Stat(stat));
    }
}
```

@PanagiotisKanavos notes that (at least based on what we've seen), the `Enums.StatName` enum isn't necessary at all. If you just use a string for `Name`, you can introduce new stats in the DB without having to alter the enum.

If you're using the enum to avoid "magic strings" (maybe some stats are referred to by name in hard-coded references), then an enum is the right thing to do, for static checking and IntelliSense. But you might want to think about keeping an enum or readonly globals for the stats the code needs to know by name, but then accept arbitrary string names from the database for stats that don't have any special status in your code. That's a bridge you don't need to cross today though.

Panagiotis also notes that you could make `CharacterStats` a subclass of `Dictionary<String, Stat>`, and avoid messing around with reflection at all. That's not a bad idea. One drawback would be the magic strings thing again: If, for example, every character has `Level`, `Damage`, etc., and the code specifically interacts with `Level`, then making `Level` a class property is sensible.

Comment: Actually, the `GetAllStats` enumerable isn't necessary at all as the property name is *already* provided by the `Stat.Name` values returned from the database

Comment: In fact, if the OP wanted to limit the DB results to specific properties only, it would be better to supply the property names as filters in a `WHERE propName IN (....)` clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True: Just make that a string and throw an exception if GetProperty() returns null.

Comment: Does `prop.SetValue` apply all properties of the `Stat` object? there are 4 properties in this class.

Comment: @levelonehuman That `prop` instance is for the property you named in its parameters: `GetType().GetProperty("Level").SetValue(this, stat)` will set the value of `this.Level`, and nothing else.

Comment: Another option would be for `CharacterStats` to store values in a dictionary instead of fields, to avoid using reflection.

Comment: @levelonehuman Ohh, I understand what you mean: My code assigns the `Stat` object instance to Level (for example). So you get the whole `Stat` object, with all its properties. myStats.Level.MinValue, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's a sound idea as well, and much more flexible for future changes.

Comment: @levelonehuman Your `GetBaseStatsFromDB()` correctly instantiates a new `Stat` every single time, so that'll work correctly (unless you copy them from one `CharacterStats` to another -- but I just added an update to address that).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and all the explanation! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: As for using the `StatName` enum, this was based on not using magic strings. Also, this lets me have all stats available in IntelliSense, which has been really nice. I've considered dictionaries but I think I'd like to keep the implementation as it is.